# Optional argument in command with click

Tags: python, python-click

I am trying to accomplish something not very standard for CLI parsing with Click and it only works partially:

- main CLI has multiple sub-commands (in sample below 'show' and 'check')
- both those commands might have optional argument, but the argument is preceding them not following
- I decided to handle that argument in the group "above" it and pass the value in the context

Sample:

```
import click

@click.group()
@click.argument('hostname', required=False)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, hostname=None):
    """"""
    ctx.obj = hostname
    click.echo("cli: hostname={}".format(hostname))

@cli.command()
@click.pass_obj
def check(hostname):
    click.echo("check: hostname={}".format(hostname))

@cli.command()
@click.pass_obj
def show(hostname):
    click.echo("check: hostname={}".format(hostname))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

The part WITH the hostname works:

```
> pipenv run python cli.py  localhost check
cli: hostname=localhost
check: hostname=localhost
> pipenv run python cli.py  localhost show
cli: hostname=localhost
check: hostname=localhost
```

But the part WITHOUT the hostname DOES NOT:

```
> pipenv run python cli.py show
Usage: cli.py [OPTIONS] [HOSTNAME] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Error: Missing command.
```

Anybody has an idea about the direction I should start looking into?

Comment: Interesting approach, but this kind of violates Click's approach.  An optional positional argument followed by a command cannot be unambiguously parsed (e.g. imagine someone named their host `show` or `check`).  It would be better to use an option instead

Comment: now click support `required=False` without Using Custom Class

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This can be done by over riding the `click.Group` argument parser like:

**Custom Class:**

```
class MyGroup(click.Group):
    def parse_args(self, ctx, args):
        if args[0] in self.commands:
            if len(args) == 1 or args[1] not in self.commands:
                args.insert(0, '')
        super(MyGroup, self).parse_args(ctx, args)
```

**Using Custom Class:**

Then to use the custom group, pass it as the `cls` argument to the `group` decorator like:

```
@click.group(cls=MyGroup)
@click.argument('hostname', required=False)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, hostname=None):
    ....
```

**How?**

This works because `click` is a well designed OO framework.  The `@click.group()` decorator usually instantiates a `click.Group` object but allows this behavior to be over ridden with the `cls` parameter.  So it is a relatively easy matter to inherit from `click.Group` in our own class and over ride desired methods.

In this case we over ride `click.Group.parse_args()` and if the first parameter matches a command and the second parameter does not, then we insert an empty string as the first parameter.  This puts everything back where the parser expects it to be.