# Click - how can I nest subcommands under a command with positional arguments?

Tags: python, click, command-line-interface, python-click

I'm in the works of transferring an [open source project's](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim) CLI from argparse to click. Currently the library allows for the following [CLI usage patterns](https://docs.manim.community/en/latest/tutorials/configuration.html#a-list-of-all-cli-flags):

```sh
manim file.py Scene1 Scene2 -p -ql
```

but also for subcommands (some with subcommands of their own), like so:

```sh
manim plugins --list
manim cfg write --level cwd
... and more.
```

Thus, the `manim` keyword is both a way to access subcommands, and more importantly, a command itself with a positional arg (the python file). In argparse, determining if the text following the `manim` keyword is a subcommand, or positional arg, is a matter of reading `sys.argv[2]` and determining whether this matches one of the available subcommands, *else* it's a positional argument. The result is a lot of effort to add subcommands and lots of boilerplate code... hence the motion to transition to click; however, this particular usage pattern doesn't seem to come out of the box in click.

In other words, the following code:

```py
    @click.group()
    @click.argument('file')
    def main(file):
        print('main',file)
    
    @main.command()
    @click.option('--opt')
    def subcommand1(opt):
        print("sub1",opt)
```

presents two issues:

1. requires the `main` Group's positional argument to be satisfied in order to run any subcommands (i.e. `main file.py subcommand1` and not `main subcommand1`)
2. it won't execute the Group + argument without a subcommand (i.e. `main file.py` is not possible without specifying subommand1 to the Group).

After further research, I've solved the second issue using the click Group parameter, `invoke_without_command`

```py
    @click.group(invoke_without_command=True)
    @click.argument('file')
    def main(file):
        print('main',file)
    
    @main.command()
    @click.option('--opt')
    def subcommand1(opt):
        print("sub1",opt)
```

but I still face issue with the 1st point -- the general ability to opt out of using the positional arg and instead invoke the subcommand. This [StackOverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47437472/in-python-click-how-do-i-see-help-for-subcommands-whose-parents-have-required) answered by Stephen Raunch seems relevant; however, it's only for the help option and not the the more general use case of arguments and options.

How can I allow for arbitrary nesting of subcommands, like a Group, but still provide the capability to execute that Group like a @click.command() with positional arguments? If this isn't a recommended pattern, what would you recommend instead?

Answer (score 0):

In doing some more research on the topic, I came across this [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056153/optional-argument-in-command-with-click) which led to the creation of this custom group:

```
import click
from click.decorators import pass_context

class SkipArg(click.Group):
    def parse_args(self, ctx, args):
        if args[0] in self.commands:
            if len(args) == 1 or args[1] not in self.commands: 
                # This condition needs updating for multiple positional arguments
                args.insert(0, '')
        super(SkipArg, self).parse_args(ctx, args)

@click.group(cls=SkipArg, invoke_without_command=True)
@click.argument('file')
@pass_context
def main(ctx, file):
    print('main',ctx,file)

@main.command()
@click.option('--opt')
def subcommand1(opt):
    print("sub1",opt)
```

This code meets the criteria of using click to have a command with positional arguments nested with more subcommands. The logic of the SkipArg will have to be updated for multiple positional arguments in the case of where I'll be using click, but is enough as a demonstration.

How it meets the criteria:

1. The `main` Group functions as a command since it is executable using `invoke_without_command`.
2. The positional argument is not required to execute subcommand1 because the class SkipArg inserts `''` into the front of the arguments list. This is a bit of hard coded logic that applies empty filler text for the [FILE] positional argument when the zeroth argument matches one of the subcommands.